# Meyer's example of a separable process with no path regularity

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

In an excerpt from Meyer's *Probability and Potentials* he claims that a non-random process $X(t, \omega) = f ( t )$ is separable for **any** choice of $f$. And this example seems to work under the definition he gives above.

[image: Paul A. Meyer, Probability and Potentials]

I cannot see, however, how this relates to other definitions of separability, especially the Doob's intuitive definition (see second attachment) as processes closable from a countable set.

[image: J. L. Doob, Stochastic process measurability conditions]

Shouldn't we at least ask for *some* regularity of $f$ in this example? Or even just measurability?

Comment: Well may be instead of Doob's definition you might look at definition 13 mentioned in the extract of Meyer's book to be sure that you are self consistent, only then we might analyze different notions between Doob's and Meyer's  formulations of separability.

Comment: @TheBridge, I specifically mentioned in the question that the example (at least to me) seems to be working under Definition 13 from this book.

Comment: I received an answer on mathoverflow, here is the [link](https://mathoverflow.net/q/437275/496689). In short, Doob's and Meyer's definitions of separability are indeed different, the latter being less restrictive. And yes, it seems that this process is Meyer-separable, but not Doob-separable.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP accepted an answer to the cross post on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437275/meyers-example-of-a-separable-process-with-no-path-regularity).